# Determine winner of games and joining with table of names

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called **players**, one called **matches**.

The **players** table contains 2 columns: id, name

The **matches** table contains 5 columns: player1, player2, goalsforplayer1, goalsforplayer2, matchid

Looking for the right query to get the names (not player id) and the result of matches, ideally comparing the goalsforplayer1 and goalsforplayer2 to get either a winner or a draw in each match. Essentially making a list of results.

Is something like this possible using a mysql query?

Comment: Change the matches table design, seems like its violating normalization standards.

Comment: @ShivaShinde this design is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two inner join on players

```
select 
   b.name as nameplayer1
 , c.name as nameplayer2
 , a.goalsforplayer1
 , a.goalsforplayer2
 , a.matchid
from matches  as a 
inner join players as b on a.player1 = b.id
inner join players as c on a.player2 = c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for (To get a list of players, and their total match results), and should guide you in the correct direction:

```
SELECT p.*, 
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN m1.goalsforplayer1 > m1.goalsforplayer2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) +
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN m2.goalsforplayer2 > m2.goalsforplayer1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    ) AS wins
FROM players p
INNER JOIN matches m1 ON p.id = m1.player1
INNER JOIN matches m2 ON p.id = m2.player2
GROUP BY p.id
```

Join on the `matches` table, and group by the ID. Use aggregation functions (`COUNT` here), to get the total number of matches that a player has won. If you want draws, simply modify the queries.

If you're looking for simple results (With players from each side), then use this:

```
SELECT p1.name AS player1, p2.name AS player2, m.goalsforplayer1, m.goalsforplayer2, m.matchid
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN players p1 ON p1.id = m.player1
INNER JOIN players p2 ON p2.id = m.player2
```